# Battleship game with different sizes?

Tags: python

I have created (followed a tutorial to creat) a simple battleship game. It works perfectly, but now I am trying to figure out how to make my ship take up multiple spaces and randomly be placed vertical or horizontal. I would like to learn what I need to do. Thank you for your time!

```
from random import randint

board = []

for i in range(0,5):
    board.append(["0"]*5)

def print_board(board):
    for i in board:
        print (" ".join(i))

print_board(board)


def random_row(board):
    return randint(0,len(board)-1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0,len(board)-1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

print(ship_row)
print(ship_col)

for turn in range(4):
    print("Turn", turn + 1)

    guess_row = int(input("Guess Row: "))
    guess_col = int(input("Guess Column: "))

    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print("You sunk my battleship!")
        break
    else:
        if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
              print("That's not even in the ocean!")
        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
              print("You guess that already.")
        else:
              print("You missed!")
              board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
              if turn == 3:
                  print("GAME OVER")
                  break
        print_board(board)
```

Comment: Have you researched any tutorial about object oriented programming yet? Implementing those principles will help significantly in understanding and debugging your code.

Comment: So for instance, your ship can be an object, your map can be an object and the player that is playing can be made an object. Once those bases are in place, you can place the game logic (this is where the user can interact with these objects) inside the main method.

Comment: I have not looked in to that. Thank you! I will do some research when I get home!